# Why is the record with id=0 renumbered when copying tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

(This question is related to [Why do I get error "1062 Duplicate entry" when copying tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65379079/4715656), but I have experimented further and now have this question).

I have a table of wines that I wish to copy to a backup table. In the original table I have an empty record with `id=0` that is copied in an unexpected way (the empty record *is* needed in my application, so I can't simply delete or move it). I guess that this has to do with the auto-increment option for the `id` column.

My table that I try to copy has the following contents:

```
Table: "mywines"
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
| id | name                           | winery           | grapes     |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
| 0  |                                |                  |            | <-- empty record!
| 1  | Champagne Tentation            | A. Bergère       |            |
| 2  | Champagne Les Clos             | A. Bergère       | Menunier   |
| 4  | Champagne Cuvée Selection      | Collard-Picard   |            |
| 8  | Les Vaupulans Chablis 1er Cru  | Vrignaud         | Chardonnay |
| 9  | Les Cotes de Fontenay 1er Cru  | Vrignaud         | Chardonnay |
| 10 | Domaine Sainte Claire          | Jean-Marc Brocard| Chardonnay |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
```

The table is constructed and designed according to the following SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE `mywines` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `winery` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `grapes` varchar(200) DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mywines` (`id`, `name`, `winery`, `grapes`) VALUES
(0, '', '', ''),
(1, 'Champagne Tentation', 'A. Bergère', ''),
(2, 'Champagne Les Clos', 'A. Bergère', 'Menunier'),
(4, 'Champagne Cuvée Selection', 'Collard-Picard', ''),
(8, 'Les Vaupulans Chablis 1er Cru', 'Vrignaud', 'Chardonnay'),
(9, 'Les Cotes de Fontenay 1er Cru', 'Vrignaud', 'Chardonnay'),
(10, 'Domaine Sainte Claire', 'Jean-Marc Brocard', 'Chardonnay');

ALTER TABLE `mywines`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `mywines`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Now... I copy this table to a backup copy. I run these SQL-commands:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mywines_copy`;
CREATE TABLE `mywines_copy`  LIKE `mywines`; 
INSERT `mywines_copy` SELECT * FROM `mywines`;
SELECT * FROM mywines_copy;
```

The last SELECT statement shows the following table:

```
Table: "mywines"
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
| id | name                           | winery           | grapes     |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
| 1  | Champagne Tentation            | A. Bergère       |            |
| 2  | Champagne Les Clos             | A. Bergère       | Menunier   |
| 4  | Champagne Cuvée Selection      | Collard-Picard   |            |
| 8  | Les Vaupulans Chablis 1er Cru  | Vrignaud         | Chardonnay |
| 9  | Les Cotes de Fontenay 1er Cru  | Vrignaud         | Chardonnay |
| 10 | Domaine Sainte Claire          | Jean-Marc Brocard| Chardonnay |
| 11 |                                |                  |            |  <-- The empty record?
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------------+
```

All record id:s are the same as in the original table, but the empty record is renumbered to `id=11`... Why is this record renumbered? How can I prevent it from being renumbered? I want it to have `id=0` even after the copy.

Comment: You have some nice wines